# Add/Modify/Delete List Items on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The assignment for my Application Development class has us creating an office system for a dentist. 
The following requirements are:

- It must display the current lists for Dentists, Assistants, Patients, and Services
- It must allow the user to add/edit/or delete items from this list
- It must display an invoice for the customer based on the chosen services

My main question revolves around the add/edit/delete portion of the assignment. I'd like to know which method would be best to do this. He did however give use the guideline that we should not use a database.

Below is what I have so far. Note: I don't need the code for all four lists, if I have one, I should be able to figure out the others.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class DentistOffice 
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   
   Patient pat1 = new Patient ("1","James","Mack","123 ABC Street","7701234567");
   Patient pat2 = new Patient ("2","Mark","Smith","456 DEF Street","6784444444");
   Patient pat3 = new Patient ("3","Doug","Barker","789 GHI Avenue","5558889999");
   
   Doctor doc1 = new Doctor ("001","Melanie","Jones","555 Doctor Avenue","DDS");
   Doctor doc2 = new Doctor ("002","Melissa","Roberts","777 Oak West","DMD");
   Doctor doc3 = new Doctor ("003","Luke","Skywalker","333 Toshe Station","DDS");
   Doctor doc4 = new Doctor ("004","Han","Solo","111 Millenium Drive","DMD");
   
   System.out.println("***************************************************************");
   System.out.println("                    Kennesaw Dental Office                     ");
   System.out.println("***************************************************************");
   System.out.println("1. Display Patient List");
   System.out.println("2. Display Doctor List");
   System.out.println("3. Display Assistant List");
   System.out.println("4. Display Service Fees");
   System.out.println("5. Edit Patient List");
   System.out.println("6. Edit Doctor List");
   System.out.println("7. Edit Assistant List");
   System.out.println("8. Edit Service Fees");
   System.out.println("9. Issue Patient Invoice");
   System.out.println("0. Exit the Program");
   
   System.out.println("Please select an option: ");
   
   int option = sc.nextInt();
   switch(option)
   
   {
   case 1: 
    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("                                   Patients                                ");
    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("Number"+" "+"First Name"+" "+"Last Name"+" "+"Address"+" "+"Phone Number");
    System.out.println(pat1.getIdentification()+pat1.getFirstName()+pat1.getLastName()+pat1.getAddress()+pat1.getPhoneNumber);
    System.out.println(pat2.getIdentification()+pat2.getFirstName()+pat2.getLastName()+pat2.getAddress()+pat2.getPhoneNumber);
    System.out.println(pat3.getIdentification()+pat3.getFirstName()+pat3.getLastName()+pat3.getAddress()+pat3.getPhoneNumber);
    break;
   
   case 2:
    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("                                   Doctors                                 ");
    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("Number"+" "+"First Name"+" "+"Last Name"+" "+"Address"+" "+"Specialization");
    System.out.println(doc1.getIdentification()+doc1.getFirstName()+doc1.getLastName()+doc1.getAddress()+doc1.getSpecialization);
    System.out.println(doc2.getIdentification()+doc2.getFirstName()+doc2.getLastName()+doc2.getAddress()+doc2.getSpecialization);
    System.out.println(doc3.getIdentification()+doc3.getFirstName()+doc3.getLastName()+doc3.getAddress()+doc3.getSpecialization);
    System.out.println(doc4.getIdentification()+doc4.getFirstName()+doc4.getLastName()+doc4.getAddress()+doc4.getSpecialization);
    break;
    
   case 3:
    break;
   
   case 4:
    break;
   
   case 5:
    break;
   }
  }
 }
```

```js
public class Doctor 
{
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String address;
 private String specialization;
 private int identification;
 
 public Doctor (int id, String fname, String lname, String add, String special)
 {
  firstName = fname;
  lastName = lname;
  address = add;
  specialization = special;
  identification = id;
 }
 
 public void setIdentification (int id)
 {
  identification = id;
 } 
 
 public int getIdentification ()
 {
  return identification;
 } 
 
 public void setFirstName (String fname)
 {
  firstName = fname;
 }
 
 public String getFirstName ()
 {
  return firstName;
 } 
 
 public void setLastName (String lname)
 {
  lastName = lname;
 } 
 
 public String getLastName ()
 {
  return lastName;
 } 
 
 public void setAddress (String add)
 {
  address = add;
 } 
 
 public String getAddress ()
 {
  return address;
 } 
 
 public void setPhoneNumber (int special)
 {
  specialization = special;
 } 
 
 public String getSpecialization ()
 {
  return specialization;
 } 
}
```

```js
public class Patient 
{
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String address;
 private int phoneNumber;
 private int identification;
 
 public Doctor (int id, String fname, String lname, String add, int phone)
 {
  firstName = fname;
  lastName = lname;
  address = add;
  phoneNumber = phone;
  identification = id;
 }
 
 public void setIdentification (int id)
 {
  identification = id;
 } 
 
 public int getIdentification ()
 {
  return identification;
 } 
 
 public void setFirstName (String fname)
 {
  firstName = fname;
 }
 
 public String getFirstName ()
 {
  return firstName;
 } 
 
 public void setLastName (String lname)
 {
  lastName = lname;
 } 
 
 public String getLastName ()
 {
  return lastName;
 } 
 
 public void setAddress (String add)
 {
  address = add;
 } 
 
 public String getAddress ()
 {
  return address;
 } 
 
 public void setPhoneNumber (int phone)
 {
  phoneNumber = phone;
 } 
 
 public int getPhoneNumber ()
 {
  return phoneNumber;
 } 
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse. Read some Java basics tutorial.

Comment: There is `pat1`, `pat2`, and `pat3`.  Where would another new patient be stored?  Consider using a List<Patient> which can be added to or removed.  Similar for Doctors.  Behavior (add/edit/delete in this case) belongs to a class (not a method).  Think about how the various objects in the assignment interact with each other.  Draw it on paper.  This should help determine which class is responsible for which behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store each instance in an `ArrayList` of type `Class`

For example: `ArrayList<Patient> list = new ArrayList<>();`

You know have an `ArrayList` of `Patient` objects.

And add them all simply like

```
list.add(pat1);
list.add(pat2);
list.add(pat3);
```

And to remove them, you can just call the `remove()` method

```
list.remove(pat2);
```

And to edit them, you can call the specific object you require, and use the set methods in the `Patient` class.

```
pat1.setFirstName("new name");
```

Note: your constructor arguments don't match what you're trying to call, so either change them as per the `Patient` class, or change the `Patient` class constructor.

Also, your `Patient` constructor is `Doctor`, but should be `Patient`. Therein lies a problem with copy/paste.